# Power BI - hybrid table scenario where table does not include date/time information

Tags: powerbi

Hybrid tables in Power BI combine (in memory) import mode and (real-time) direct query mode.

However the distinction is based on time periods.

*Hybrid tables – tables which contain both Import mode and DirectQuery mode
partitions to hold data from different time periods*

(ref https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/)

How does one handle a scenario where table does not include date/time information ?

For example a table with users.

A user **name** will never (or rarely) change but the **state** can change regularly.

| fName | lName | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | doe | logged_in |
| june | doe | logged_out |

This seems like a good fit for a hybrid configuration.

Column **fName** and **lName** are in import mode while column **state** is in direct query mode.

Is this at all possible in Power BI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Column fName and lName are in import mode while column state is in direct query mode.
> Is this at all possible in Power BI ?

Not directly, no.  A hybrid table has one or more DirectQuery partitions.  A partition is a bunch of rows.

You would normally just import that table.

Comment: Thanks for this David. Is there a way to partition on a column level ?

Comment: You can have two separate tables with a 1-1 relationship.